# Create an array using a function - Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, arrays, function, objective-c++

I want to create an array from a function. The following obviously works, however because my arrays are much larger I want to save the space and the time writing them out.

```
GLfloat gCubeTextureData_floorj[2] = { 1.0, 1.0 };
```

In my attempts to create an array from a function, I am getting the error that 'Array initializer must be an initializer list'. However I am initializing the array by returning the list. This is my function call:

```
 GLfloat array[2] = [self createCubeTextureFromX1:0.5f toX2:1.0f toY1:0.0f andY2:0.5f];
```

I have tried the following for the function:

```
-(GLfloat[2]) createCubeTextureFromX1:(float)x1 toX2:(float)x2 toY1:(float)y1 andY2:(float)y2 {
    GLfloat gCubeTextureData_floorj[2] = { 1.0, 1.0 };
    return gCubeTextureData_floorj;
}
```

and I have tried

```
-(GLfloat[2]) createCubeTextureFromX1:(float)x1 toX2:(float)x2 toY1:(float)y1 andY2:(float)y2 {
    return { 1.0, 1.0 };
}
```

and both of these don't work. The first gives me the error in the function, the second gives me the error on the function call.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: what language are you using then? you have three languages tagged

Comment: My compiler is set to Objective-C++, so I can use any of the three languages. However, I would prefer to use Objective-C (or Objective-C++) as you can see from my function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In C, arrays are typically returned using pointers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416074/return-an-array-in-c)

To do this properly in Objective-C, I'd suggest returning a NSArray from your method.

However, GLFloats aren't native Objective-C objects that can be stored directory in NSArray. To get around this, I'd recommend using NSNumber or NSValue objects to contain your GLfloat values.

Comment: The problem with using NSArray and NSNumber is I need to then use the values in glBufferData which I wouldn't know how to do. (OpenGL ES program)

Comment: Whatever you insert into an NSMutableArray going in, you can extract from the (mutable or immutable) NSArray on the other end via "`objectAtIndex:`". Once you get comfortable with Objective-C arrays it'll become easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to initialize a C array from a function, method, $whatever. It can be only initialized with an initializer list.
ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, § 6.7.8, 16.
"Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace- enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members."

What you can do:

Instead of the C array use a pointer. Heap alloc an array in the creation function or method and return the pointer of the array. The caller is responsible for freeing it.

Comment: Ah, an addition: IIRC in C++ you can assign arrays. But my knowledge of C++ is that old, that I do not know the details.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a C99 compound literal?

```
- (float[2])fooX:(float)x andY:(float)y
{
    return (float[2]){ x, y };
}
```

Comment: That still gives the 'Array initializer must be an initializer list' eror

Comment: @michaellindahl [No, it doesn't.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4960980/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-15%20at%208.59.44%20PM.png)

Comment: It does when initializing a C array.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Platform, compiler, compiler flags, etc...?

Comment: Mac OS – clang/LLVM – standard
You assign the retval to a pointer, not to an array. This is, what I wanted to say in my answer.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I see - we were talking about different parts of the problem.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes 1. He can use compound literals, 2. but without changing the type of the var to pointer, he will get the error again.

Comment: Interesting... How come Objective-C methods can return array type? while C functions can't? Is this documented somewhere? Also interestingly, getting the method signature of this using `methodSignatureForSelector:` throws an exception. The type encoding for the return type is "[2f]"